# input unknown number of variables in one line(In C++)

Tags: c++

I want to take input in vector of unknown number of numbers in one line.
For instance
3
1 1 2
Here I know from first input that there are 3 numbers. But I dont know how to store the 3 numbers in the next line in a vector array.
Another instance-
4
2 3 2 3
I want this in C++(vector).

Comment: Use a while or for loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
int n, x;
std::vector<int> v;
if (std::cin >> n)
    while (n--)
        if (std::cin >> x)
            v.push_back(x);
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("missing value");
else
    throw std::runtime_error("missing count");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    std::cin >> count;
    // check that count is correct

    std::vector<int> vec;

    // input
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), count, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int> >(vec)); // std::copy_n is part of C++11

    // show vector
    std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); // std::begin() and std::end() are part of C++11

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

vector<int> numbers;
string str;
int x;

getline (cin, str);
stringstream ss(str);
while (ss >> x)
    numbers.push_back(x);
```

If I enter something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

The vector contains exactly those numbers, and goes on to execute the next line of code, instead of looping back to get more input from the user

Comment: +1 Your code doesn't handle the leading count-of-values, so isn't suitable for the input in the question, but it's likely more convenient and intuitive if the input doesn't have to have a count....